Why is this line of reasoning in proving that these sets are linear continua wrong?
I have a doubt about an exercise. I have the actual solution, and i understand it, but i don't understand why my initial approach to the exercise is completely off. Here is the exercise:
Which of the following sets in the dictionary order is a linear continuum?
(By linear continua i mean an (simply) ordered set with least upper bound property and for which, given any $a < b$, there exists $c$ s.t. $a < c < b$)

$\mathbb{Z}_{+} \times[0,1)$
$[0,1)\times\mathbb{Z}_{+}$
$[0,1)\times[0,1]$
$[0,1]\times[0,1)$

My line of reasoning was that when a set is in the order topology, it being connected is equivalent to being a linear continua. Since both [0,1] and [0,1) are connected, their product is connected and therefore a linear continua. Therefore I would conclude that 3 and 4 are linear continua. In 1 and 2 i can't apply this reasoning because Z is not connected, therefore i would have to check explicitly if 1 and 2 are linear continua in this topology.
The actual solution proves directly that 1 and 3 and linear continua by checking the l.u.b. property and the intermediate value property, but I still don't understand why i can't reason like i did.

"simply ordered" or "totally ordered" or "linearly ordered". they are all synonymous.

Your characterization of linear continua by connectedness is correct. The flaw in your reasonings is that on these various product sets, you are confusing the topology of the dictionary order (aka lexicographic order) with the usual product topology. For instance, for the lexicographic order:

your first set, $\Bbb Z_+\times[0,1)$, is isomorphic (as an ordered set) to $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb Z_+}[n,n+1)=[1,∞)$ (with the usual ordering), hence the two associated topological spaces (for the corresponding order topologies) are homeomorphic. Since the latter is $[1,∞)$ with the usual topology, it is connected,

whereas

your fourth set, $[0,1]\times[0,1)$, is not connected, being the union of the two disjoint open subsets $\{0\}\times[0,1)$ and $(0,1]\times[0,1)$.


But doesn't the lexicographical order induces a topology which is still an order topology? different from the usual one, but still with open intervals as basis. So your saying that since it's homeomorphic to [0,∞) in the order topology, and since this is connected, then I can conclude that ℤ+×[0,1) is a linear continuum?

I added some details in my answer. Are they sufficient?

Only one thing about the last set.
Isn't [0,1]×[0,1) still a finite product of connected spaces? therefore I would expect it to be connected.

The end of my answer proves it is not connected. It is not "a finite product of connected spaces". This shows that the topology of a lexicographic order is (generally) not the product of the two order topologies.
